# Re.search of Dates with backslash characters in the format

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I will say thanks in advance for any assistance and say that I have tried to search online for a solution.

I'm running Python 2.7.

I'm trying to use re.search to match a date in the format `mm\dd\yyyy`. If I modify the format slightly to `mm-dd-yyyy`, I'm successful. I've had no luck with examples that Include  the backslash. I recognize that backslashes are special and must be "escaped".

I've tried the following:

```
line = '7\22\2012'
line2 = '7-22-2012'

print re.search("[0-9]*\-[0-9]*\-[0-9]*", line2).group()
print re.search('\d*\-\d*\-\d*',line2).group()

print re.search(r'\d*\\d*\\d*',line)
print re.search('\d*\\\d*\\\d*',line)
```

Again, any assistance will be greatly appreciated.
Liam

Answer (score 0):

The correct regex would be `r'\d*\\\d*\\\d*'`.

You also need to define the string you want to search/match (`line`) either as a raw string: `line = r'7\22\2012'` or with escaped backslashes: `line = '7\\22\\2012'`.

The following is a working example:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'\d*\\\d*\\\d*', r'7\22\2012').group(0)
'7\\22\\2012'
```